# How can I change the position of UILabel within a cell of a tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview, uilabel

I would like to move the position of a UIlabel within a cell of a UICollectionView so that the Y value of the UILabel is 100 higher.

It's position is already set in the storyboard but I would like the position to change under a set of conditions such as where the UIImage in the cell isn't needed.

I have tried various options including below without succes

cell.flashLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 70, width: 230, height: 60)

Comment: How are you linking the flashLabel variable to the label?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to check this at the moment but have you tried 
`cell.setsNeedsLayout` or `cell.setsNeedsDisplay`?

This should update the cells views to the new frame. Call one or the other after setting your frame.

Let me know if that works. If not, I can take a look when I get out of work.

`- Amir`

Answer (score 0):

You could try linking the top constraint of the label to an outlet. You would then be able to manipulate the constraint using:

```
cell.topConstraint.constant = 70 //whatever point value is needed
```